# "Too big for X to eat"

Tags: prepositions

I once translated the sentence

> Is a duck too big for a monad to eat?

to

> Ĉu anaso estas tro granda por monado manĝi?

According to an expert friend, it seems that this is incorrect. My next guesses were

> Ĉu anaso estas tro granda por monado por manĝi?
>   Ĉu anaso estas tro granda por manĝi por monado?
>   Por/Al/Laŭ monado, ĉu anaso estas tro granda por manĝi?

I never showed him these guesses yet, so I don't know if any of these are correct. His suggestion to me, however, was

> Ĉu anaso estas tro granda por ke monado manĝu [ĝin].

Yes, I understand his suggestion and why it works (in fact, I now prefer this form, at the moment), but now I am curious about two things.

1. What other ways are there to equivalently express this sentence?
2. What makes my initial guesses incorrect?

I do remember reading about this in the PMEG, but I do not recall the precise rule(s) for this specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. What other ways are there to equivalently express this sentence?

I don't know if equivalently, but you could also say it like this:

```
Ĉu anaso estas tro granda por esti manĝita de X?
```

> 2. What makes my initial guesses incorrect?

Check [this page](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/ceteraj/tro.html) in PMEG about *tro*. The answers to this post are in the [section *Tro + klariga esprimo*](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/ceteraj/tro.html#i-ehl).

> *Tro* ofte aperas kun klariga esprimo, kiu montras, kiel estus, aŭ kio povus okazi, se la troeco ne ekzistus.
>
> La klariga esprimo povas esti subfrazo kun *ke* aŭ *por ke*. Tiaj subfrazoj havas normale ĉefverbon en U-formo, malofte en US-formo [...] La klariga esprimo povas ankaŭ esti *por + I-verbo*.

Comment: @das-g I quoted the relevant parts.

Comment: So we can conclude that, as a general rule, “tro granda por manĝi is OK” but if you need to add a subject before “manĝi” it's better to change it to “ke X manĝu”. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @marcus, _X estas tro granda por manĝi_ signifus ke pro ĝia grandeco X ne plu povas manĝi. Komparu kun _X estas tro granda por flugi_. Tio ne vere rilatas la demandon supran.

Comment: Mi pensas ke tio ja rilatas al la temo ĉar unu el la demandoj estas: "2. What makes my initial guesses incorrect?", do necesas klarigi gramatikajn eblojn kaj malebojn.

Krome, via komento aldonis bonan informon kaj povus esti parto de via respondo. Mi ankaŭ aldonus: https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/i-verboj/index.html

Answer (score 1):

In a sentence like

> Is a duck too big for a monad to eat?

we have a subject (a monad) and a non-finite or a shortened clause, *klariga esprimo* or *frazekvivalento*, with an object (a duck). In the English grammar these non-finite clauses are called to-infinitive clauses:

- He gave up his job **to travel** the world.
- We wanted to ask her **to come** along.

which IMHO is a misnomer, because it doesn't clearly tell that the non-finite clause is the goal or expresses the intenction. As others have pointed out, Esperanto uses a *(por) ke + u(s)-modo* subclause for this purpose.

Should the action be directed towards the subject itself, you can omit the subclause and use only *por + i-formo* as a *frazekvivalento*

- *Ĉu mi estas tro vigla por ke mi ekdormus?*
- *Ĉu mi estas tro vigla por ekdormi?*

Answer (score 0):

The implied being able (*-ebl*) to be eaten (passive tense).

> Ĉu anaso estas tro granda por esti manĝebla de X?

> Ĉu anaso estas tro granda por ke X povus manĝi ĝin?

> Ĉu anaso estas tro granda por ke X manĝus ĝin? [different meaning]

X being the subject of eating, and the eating being in conditional tense,
either a *-us* subphrase or *-ebla*.